# Are body bags medical waste?

Tags: viscera-cleanup-detail

Do body bags count as medical waste? Should they get placed into the *medical waste* area if one exists, or can they be incinerated as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body bags **do not** count as medical waste, **only** medical waste crates do. They should get burned just like other hazardous material. If you don't incinerate them, you end up with an ending message that reports a mishap with one of the leftover body bags.